# Ubuntu randomly change resolution by itself to 1024x768

Tags: 13.04, resolution, intel-graphics

I'm running 13.04 on an IBM machine with integrated intel graphics on a 1920x1080 monitor.
When I boot up, the resolution is fine for a couple of seconds and then the screen goes black, and the display change to **1024x768** resolution. 
I am able to temporally fix the issue by just opening the display setting screen and (very stragely) the screen comes back to my 1920x1080 optimal resolution. I have to do this every time I boot up, lock the computer, or open some applications for the first time (ex. google chrome). I tried to install drivers for intel graphics, event though I read that they are already supported by ubuntu. I have a dual boot setup with Windows 7 and the problem only occur in Ubuntu.

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: For those wondering how to fix this: 
It turns out that my screen resolution was not correctly detected. I fixed it by permanatly setting the resolution in /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Thanks to this post:
http://rolling-ubuntu.blogspot.ca/2012/09/how-to-permanently-change-screen.html

Comment: Could you post that comment as an answer, so that this question doesn't show up in the unanswered questions?

Comment: Actualy I could't because I'm a new user. Be it seems I can now!

Comment: Thanks. You'll be able to accept your own answer tomorrow evening; ie. 48 hours after your initial question was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering how to fix this: 
It turns out that my screen resolution was not correctly detected. I fixed it by permanatly setting the resolution in /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Thanks to this post:
http://rolling-ubuntu.blogspot.ca/2012/09/how-to-permanently-change-screen.html