# Resolution set to 1024x768 out of nowhere

Tags: display, display-resolution

I rebooted my computer and now the screen's resolution is stuck at 1024x768 (can't pick any other). It's usually 1920x1080. I have no idea why this happened or how to fix it, I tried making a `xorg.conf` file and pasting the code presented on [this](http://rolling-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-permanently-change-screen.html) website but nothing changed. I found this link on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317906/ubuntu-randomly-change-resolution-by-itself-to-1024x768) post where it worked for the other person.

Here's the output I get when I type `xrandr`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

And here is the output of `sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Any help is deeply appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Could be an update. I applied an updated this morning (as I thought it was only a Chrome update) and now Ubuntu boots to low resolution. I'm hoping a further update will come through to fix it, but for now I've selected the previous kernel from the Grub boot menu and all is OK for now.

Comment: Yup, just tried the same thing and it worked for me! Interesting, thank you for your help :)